# Group treated result in separated columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a new situation for me! I must have a treated result (with distinct clauses) grouped by registry.

I’m currently having the result in only one column, but I need that information in others to avoid “duplicated rows”.

Basically, I have the tables bellow:

**Table 1 (USER)**

```
USER_ID | USER_NAME
U001    | John
U002    | Peter
```

**Table 2 (COURSE)**

```
COURSE_ID | COURSE_NAME
C01       | AAA
C02       | BBB
C03       | CCC
```

**Table 3 (CLASS)**

```
CLASS_ID | COURSE_ID
001      | C01
002      | C01
003      | C01
```

**Table 4 (ASSIGNMENT a)**

```
USER | CLASS_ID | COURSE_ID | ADD_USER | SEQ_NUM
U001 | NULL     | C01       | S        | 000001
U001 | 001      | C01       | S        | 000002
U002 | NULL     | C02       | U        | 000003
U002 | NULL     | C01       | U        | 000004
U002 | 002      | C01       | U        | 000005
```

Where:
**ADD_USER** *(to know by who the assignment was generated)*
S = Supervisor
U = User

**SEQ_NUM**
Is unique and PK

So, with the CASE below I haven't a satisfactory result.

```
CASE
  WHEN a.CLASS_ID IS NULL AND a.ADD_USER = 'U' THEN 'Self'
  WHEN a.CLASS_ID IS NULL AND a.ADD_USER = 'S' THEN 'Supervisor'
  ELSE 'Enroll'
END AS "ORIGIN"


ORIGIN     | USER_ID | CLASS_ID | COURSE_ID
Supervisor | U001    | NULL     | C01
Enroll     | U001    | 001      | C01
Self       | U002    | NULL     | C02
Self       | U002    | NULL     | C01
Enroll     | U002    | 002      | C01
```

My expected result is:

```
SELF | SUP  | CLASS | CLASS_ID | COURSE_ID
NULL | Y    | Y     | 001      | C01
Y    | NULL | NULL  | NULL     | C02
Y    | NULL | Y     | 002      | C01
```

We can note that the results are grouped by USER_ID and COURSE_ID.

How can I do this in Oracle 11g?

Comment: In your `CASE` What is `a.ADD_USER = 'P'` ?

Comment: a.SCHD_ID - ? can you show the entire select statement

Comment: You need to explain when you expect `Y` or `NULL` for columns `{SELF, SUP, CLASS}`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, `'a'` is my alias for `ASSIGNMENT` table // `ADD_USER` is the collumn that contain the user's origin assignment. So, I can know if was by himself, by supervisor or adm (them will appear `'A'`).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, `Y` or `NULL` are based in the `CASE` condition. I could change `NULL` for `N`, for example.

Comment: @RavshanAbdulaev, I'm sorry, I fixed the `CASE` condition. And I can't show  the entire select because I have others JOINS. What information do you need?

Comment: Your `ASSIGNMENT` table shows `ADD_USER` values of U or S, but your case statement shows values of P or S. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @kfinity, OMG! I fixed again! Yes, it was a mistake! Consider `U` instead of `P`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found was to JOIN the same table to have the result separated (with specific arguments per JOIN).

In my case, was necessary to JOIN again (inside table_CLASS) to have others class information, ensuring an effective result.

Bellow a part of the query that I used:

```
    SELECT
        "SELF",
        "SUP",
        "CLASS",
        u.USER_ID,
        cla.CLASS_ID,
        c.COURSE_ID

    FROM
        ASSIGNMENT a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                USER_ID,
                CLASS_ID,
                COURSE_ID,
                'Y' AS "SELF"
            FROM ASSIGNMENT
            WHERE
                CLASS_ID IS NULL AND
                ADD_USER = 'P'
        )self ON
            self.USER_ID = a.USER_ID AND
            self.COURSE_ID = a.COURSE_ID

        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                USER_ID,
                CLASS_ID,
                COURSE_ID,
                'Y' AS "SUP"
            FROM ASSIGNMENT
            WHERE
                CLASS_ID IS NULL AND
                ADD_USER = 'S'
        )sup ON
            sup.USER_ID = a.USER_ID AND
            sup.COURSE_ID = a.COURSE_ID

        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                ac.USER_ID,
                ac.CLASS_ID,
                ac.COURSE_ID,
                'Y' AS "CLASS"
            FROM ASSIGNMENT ac
            INNER JOIN table_CLASS c ON c.CLASS_ID = ac.CLASS_ID
            WHERE
                ac.CLASS_ID IS NOT NULL AND
        )cla ON
            cla.USER_ID = a.USER_ID AND
            cla.COURSE_ID = a.COURSE_ID

        INNER JOIN table_USER u ON u.USER_ID = a.USER_ID
        LEFT JOIN table_USER s ON u.SUPER = s.USER_ID   -- supervisor x user
        INNER JOIN table_COURSE c ON c.COURSE_ID = a.COURSE_ID

    WHERE
        1=1
        AND a.ADD_USER NOT IN ('A', 'I') -- 'A' = adm // 'I' = instructor
        AND ("SELF" IS NOT NULL OR "SUP" IS NOT NULL ) -- to show only results that have self and/or sup assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an awkward way to do it, but it's the first thing that came to mind.

```
with assignment as (select 'U001' as user_id, null as class_id, 'C01' as course_id, 'S' as add_user from dual
                union all
                select 'U001' as user_id, '001' as class_id, 'C01' as course_id, 'S' as add_user from dual
                union all
                select 'U002' as user_id, null as class_id, 'C02' as course_id, 'U' as add_user from dual
                union all
                select 'U002' as user_id, null as class_id, 'C01' as course_id, 'U' as add_user from dual
                union all
                select 'U002' as user_id, '002' as class_id, 'C01' as course_id, 'U' as add_user from dual)
-- everything above this is just sample data
select
    max(CASE when a.class_id is null and a.add_user = 'U' then 'Y' ELSE null END) as "Self",
    max(CASE when a.class_id is null and a.add_user = 'S' then 'Y' ELSE null END) as "Sup",
    max(CASE when a.class_id is not null then 'Y' ELSE null END) as "Class",   
    a.user_id, max(a.class_id) as class_id, a.course_id
from assignment a
group by a.user_id, a.course_id
order by user_id, course_id desc;
```

I added an ORDER BY statement just to get the output rows to line up with what you wanted; it's not required. I'm also assuming that you have some logic in place to prevent a user from being enrolled in more than one class of the same course - otherwise you might want a LISTAGG instead of MAX for the CLASS_ID column.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't fix or predict IDs in query. About avoid users to enroll in more than one class, this is ok.

Comment: maybe you should add a more complex sample data. because this solution works for your question. Unless you elaborate in why is wrong.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, because the table ASSIGNMENT is constantly fed by n users, n courses, n classes, and go on.

Comment: @IgorIvanov still isnt clear why this doesnt solve it.

Comment: @IgorIvanov, the top `WITH assignment` section is only included as a dummy ASSIGNMENT table. The bottom half of the query is what you want, I think. I edited to be more clear.

Comment: @kfinity, thank you for explanation! Works, but I have another solution too! But I appreciate to learn other possibilities.